# Mvc: Same ActionResult with different name depending url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

I would like to know what's the best way to achieve this.

I have an `ActionResult` in my controller, actually it has `news` name, now I need to internationlize my website and I can't have the same `news` name, it must to change depending the country where it's visited.

for example, now I need something like.

`www.something.com/en/us/news` for english version

`www.something.com/co/es/noticias` for spanish version

you have the point for the next countries.

I don't think I need to create **x methods** depending **x urls** that make exactly the same, but I don't know how to achieve it in a really efficient way ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new class TranslatedRoute and TranslationProvider to map the different translations to the same action. Then you can plug these into the routing system and override the default mapping.

Here's a good blog post which describes the idea: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How does your routing work now? Maybe something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103167/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-strategy-and-internationalization) would work, if you don't already use it. Perhaps something variation of this, with the parts of the URL in a different order, to suit your needs. For example, the controller doesn't necessarily have to come first in the route (or at all, in this case just always using the same controller name). Make some sort of map that gets you the word "news" in each different language, using the language code as a key.

```
// populate this map somewhere - language code to word for "news" (and any other name of the controllers that you have)
var newsControllerMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newsControllerMap["en"] = "news"; // etc.

// ...

// inside of the RouteConfig class (MVC 4) or RegisterRoutes() method in Global.asax.cs (MVC 3)
// just making an assumption that whatever class/entity you use ("LanguageAndCountry" in this case) also has a country code to make this easier. Obviously this would be refactored to have better naming/functionality to make sense and meet your needs.
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    LanguageAndCountryRepository langRepo = new LanguageAndCountryRepository();
    var languagesandCountries = langRepo.GetAllLanguagesWithCountries();

    foreach (LanguageAndCountry langAndCountry in languagesandCountries)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        "LocalizationNews_" + langAndCountry.LanguageAbbreviation,
        langAndCountry.LanguageAbbreviation + "/" + langAndCountry.CountryCode + "/" + newsControllerMap[langAndCountry.LanguageAbbreviation],
        new { lang = language.LanguageAbbreviation, country = langAndCountry.CountryCode, controller = "News", action = "Index"});

        // map more routes to each controller you have, each controller having a corresponding map to the name of the controller in any given language
    }
```